# JPAContainer filter like?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I'm trying make a "search by name" using JPAContainer Filter. Using Compare I still didn't have success. The comparison doesn't work, for example if I enter name: fernando, the filter doesn't work.

I'm trying this.

```
TextField searchByName = new TextField();
searchByName.setInputPrompt("Search by name");
searchByName.addBlurListener(new BlurListener() {           
@Override
public void blur(BlurEvent event) {
    nameFilter();
}
});


/** filter by name */
private void nameFilter(){
    if(!searchByName.getValue().isEmpty()){         
        Filter filter = new Compare.Equal("name", searchByName.getValue());
        datasource.addContainerFilter(filter);
    }
}
```

There's some way search with LIKE ???

Comment: there is ``com.vaadin.data.util.filter.Like`` -- but i have never worked with JPAContainer so this is just guesswork

Comment: very nice man, now works :D !!!

Comment: then i'll be so bold and write an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is [com.vaadin.data.util.filter.Like](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/data/util/filter/Like.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
mySQLContainer.addContainerFilter(
    new Or(new And(new Equal("NAME", "Paul"),
                   new Or(new Less("AGE", 18),
                          new Greater("AGE", 65))),
           new Like("NAME", "A%")));
```